# Macro to number column A based on value in column R

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am looking for a macro that will automatically number Column A in order (1,2,3...) based on the value in column R.  The numbering begins on line 6.

So for example, I would want A6 to say "1" if R6 says "Yes".  I would want A7 to say "2" if R7 says "Yes" but would want A7 to be blank if R7 says "No" and then A8 would be "2" if R8 says "yes".

Let me know if this doesn't make sense... I can send screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw a neat and simple solution to a similar problem:

This formula

```
 =IF(R6="Yes",MAX($A$5:A6)+1,"")
```

in A6 and filled down, gives the desired result:

[image]

Thanks to @EricF for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Will you settle for a formula or two?

First of all, the `COUNTIF(range, condition)` function does almost exactly what you want: count the number of cells within a range that meet a given condition.  In this case, your condition is "contains the string `Yes`."  If we just use this formula by itself, though, you'll get a bunch of repeated values when the cell says "No", so we have to do a little bit of extra checking.

In cell A6, put the formula
`=IF(COUNTIF($R$6:R6,"Yes")=0,"",COUNTIF($R$6:R6,"Yes"))`
This establishes a base point for the rest of the values.

In cell A7, put the formula `=IF(COUNTIF($R$6:R7,"Yes")=COUNTIF($R$6:R6,"Yes"),"",COUNTIF($R$6:R7,"Yes"))`
This one says that if the count up to the current cell is the same as the count at the previous cell, leave this cell blank; otherwise display the count value.

Then copy cell A7 down for the rest of the range.